# Finding the sum of grouped data by column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

My grouped data looks like:

```
deviceid                                  time          total_sent
022009f075929be71975ce70db19cd47780b112f  1980-January  36            4
                                                        52            1
                                                        94            1
                                                        211           1
                                                        278           1
                                                        318           2
                                                        370           1
                                                        426           1
                                                        430           1
                                                        435           1
                                                        560           1
                                                        674           1
                                                        797           1
                                                        813           4
                                                        816           1

ff5b22df4ab9207bb6709cddef6d95c655565578  2013-August  11308408       4
                                                       12075616       1
                                                       17933654       1
                                                       22754808      12
                                                       22754987       1
                                                       22755166       3
                                                       22755345       4
                                                       22788586       4
                                                       22788765       2
                                                       22788944       2
                                                       22791830       1
                                                       22792546       1
                                                       22796843       1
                                                       22797201       2
                                                       22797380       2
```

Where the last column represents the count. I obtained this grouped representation using the expression:

```
data1.groupby(['deviceid', 'time', 'total_sent'])
```

How do I sum the total_sent per month?

```
deviceid                                  time            sum    
022009f075929be71975ce70db19cd47780b112f  1980-January    6210
ff5b22df4ab9207bb6709cddef6d95c655565578  2013-August     XXXX
```

Comment: Does the sum need to take ``count`` column into account?

Comment: No it doesn't. Can I avoid the count when performing the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `total_sent` column is to be summed, it shouldn't be within the groupby keys. You can try the following:

```
data1.groupby(['deviceid', 'time']).agg({'total_sent': sum})
```

which will sum the `total_sent` column for each group, indexed by `deviceid` and `time`.

Comment: If I also wanted to find the average, how would I do it?

For instance, I want to find the average for all the months of deviceid X which essentially is sum of all the total_sent for all months of deviceid X divided by the number of months.

Comment: @user866098 If you meant the average of the `total_sent` column, you can just change ``sum`` to for example ``np.mean``.

Comment: but it is still grouped by ['deviceid', 'time'], right? What will the mean represent in this case?

Comment: In this case, it is the mean of the ``total_sent`` having the same ``device_id`` and ``time`` (similar to ``sum``'s case). If the granularity of ``time`` column is month, then you get the monthly average.

Comment: Yes, but what I want is the sum that your described in the answer divided by the number of months that contributed to that sum.